# My Unity Project on Phone/Tablet looks Horrible

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, user-interface

Inside Unity Editor my project looks fine but when I play and I use unity remote on my tablet/phone it looks horrible anybody knows why?

This is the Unity Editor Screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4SJG.png)

Comment: Chances are something is wrong but since you have literally shared nothing about your project or what it looks like I can't begin to imagine what.

Comment: I can't get a screenshot from my tablet.

Comment: You have not provided enough detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it will look horrible if you are using Unity Remote. It's downsizing image projected to your phone, otherwise bandth of USB cable will not be enough.
[image]
I recommend to build app and install apk to test your app. There are too many problems that you just can't catch using Unity Remote. Like Input Controls. I always had problems with touches even tho in editor and Remote all worked just fine.

Comment: So even if I put the resolution to normal it still looks pretty bad it's still because of the Unity Remote Right? If yes I am going to build the apk

Comment: Yes, build apk and install it.

Comment: @Teroro If that solved your question can you select my answer?